# Calculating $H_1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Given the space $X=\mathbb{R}$, how can we calculate its first homology group $H_1(\mathbb{R})$? Intuitively, the object of first homology describes 1-dimensioal holes in the set which here doesn't exist, hence maybe $$H_1(\mathbb{R})=\{0\}?$$ If my intuition is right: how do we prove that?

**EDIT:** I'm using simplicial homology means the quotient group $$H_n(X)=\ker\partial_n\big/\text{Im}\partial_{n+1}$$

Comment: You need to start with the actual definition. If your definition is via something like simplicial homology, you can do this by hand; if you're using singular homology, you're going to want to use homotopy invariance.

Comment: What type of homology are you using?

Comment: If you're using simplicial homology, you need to start by triangulating $\Bbb R$. It should not be terribly hard to actually calculate what $\text{ker}(\partial_1)$ is; it should be even easier to calculate $\text{Im}(\partial_2)$.

Comment: the kernel is not all the 1-simplicies $\sigma$ s.t. $\sigma(0)=\sigma(1)$? About the image I'm a bit in trouble (though it seems like the image is the 1-simplicies).

Comment: Had you had Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms?

Comment: Not yet. Is there any good way to proceed (maybe proving the homology of every convex set is trivial?)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using simplicial homology, you first need to equip $\Bbb R$ with a $\Delta$-complex structure. You can do so by choosing the integers $\tau_n:\Delta^0\to\{n\}$ as the $0$-simplices, and the closed intervals $\sigma_n:\Delta^1\to[n,n+1]$ as the $1$-simplices. Then $\partial_1:C_1(X)\to C_0(X)$ sends $\sigma_n$ to $\tau_{n+1}-\tau_n$. Can you see why $\text{Ker}(\partial_1)$ is trivial?

Comment: The kernel is trivial but what about the $\text{Im}(\partial_0)$?

Comment: Why would you need $\partial_0$ for the calculation? I suppose you mean $\text{Im}(\partial_2)$. But you don't need that either, since $\text{Ker}(\partial_1)=\{0\}$ already implies that $H_1(X)$ is trivial.